# Use external program in PHP on an in-memory image

Tags: php, external, in-memory

I have a string image (png) which I can convert to an image ressource with `imagecreatefromstring()`.
I know I can compress it with `imagepng()` but I'd like to go further using Optipng.
Optipng take a file as an input.

So how I can use Optipng or any other command line tool in PHP on an in-memory image? Writing to disk the image first is not an option.

Comment: Only with shared memory, but that has to be supported by both sides (ie. without proper techniques, two processes can't share their memory).
You can google for "shared memory" to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should save it to some temporary place, perform required operation and read it back to string if need.
Code below allows you to save data on temp file:

```
   $tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'tmp_img') . '.png';
   file_put_contents($tmp, $data);

   $command = "optipng -o7 ${tmp}>/dev/null; echo $?";
   $retCode = shell_exec($command);
   if ($retCode == 0) {
       $data = file_get_contents($tmp);
   } else {
       die("error");
   }
```